# please, explain "the" in "the school assemblies"

Tags: definite-article

Please, explain to me the usage of "the" in the bold in the text:

> The other kids could mutter all they want and make fun of him, but Chad knew they wished their dads were as daring as his. **The** school assemblies that Bruce Michaels spoke at each year were always the most popular and talked about.

Comment: It identifies a particular subset of all the school's assemblies: **the** ones at which Bruce Michaels spoke.

Answer (score -1):

Although I cannot explain in formal 'English class' language, I believe it has something to do with

"...each year...".

Compare these three sentences:

> a) The school assemblies that Bruce Michaels spoke at each year were always the most popular and talked about.
>
> b) School assemblies that Bruce Michaels spoke at were always the most popular and talked about.
>
> c) The school assemblies that Bruce Michaels spoke at were always the most popular and talked about.

These all sound natural, but it doesn't sound very natural to me to say:

> School assemblies that Bruce Michaels spoke at each year were always the most popular and talked about.

A possible explanation is that if Bruce Michaels is speaking at school assemblies, but **not habitually**, *the* is optional but possibly better left out. To contrast, if Bruce Michaels is speaking at school assemblies **each year**, these assemblies can be described as a series of events. A *specific* series of events.  *The* indicates a specific thing because that's what it's for.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think that the specificity comes from _"... that Bruce Michaels spoke at"_ as opposed to _"each year"_. Some sentences I can think of that seem to be counterexamples to your answer are "_Barbecues held at my friend's house **each summer** were always very fun_" or "_Stores that close **each time** there is a thunderstorm drive me crazy._"

Comment: @Kman3 Personally, I would put "the" in front of both sentences. Maybe it's a stylistic choice?

Comment: Maybe! I'm not too sure. Even though I'm a native speaker, I can't really say with absolute certainty.

Comment: @Kman3 On second thought, I would not put "the" in front of the second sentence. The difference for me is that "each time there is a thunderstorm" is not a regular event, i.e. it doesn't happen precisely once a week. A summer happens regularly, exactly once per year. I would, however, change "each" to "every" in the second sentence, but that's probably stylistic as well :)